# HTML Print: Avoid page break for table row with rowspan, add page number

Tags: html, css, printing, page-break, page-break-inside

I have a number of issues with printing an html page. I spent some time and tried different solutions but none works.

http://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/vj7hr1cg/1/ - here's the table that I want to print. I simplified it as much as possible. It does not fit in one page and the goal is to avoid page break inside the row content.

Also I want to have some custom text at the bottom of each printed page like 'page 1 of 10'.

Here's the current result:

[image: Invalid page break, no page number]

As we see, the last cell does not fit in a page, it does not have the bottom border, the page number printed as 1/5 instead of '1 of 5' that's specified in css.

Here's what I tried so far:

Each row with rowspan has `-primary` class name. Page breaks avoided anywhere but before such rows:

```
.b-rtable__row, .b-rtable__cell {
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
.b-rtable__row {
  page-break-before: avoid !important;
  page-break-after: avoid !important;
}
.b-rtable__row.-primary {
  page-break-before: auto !important;
}
```

Wrapped each cell content into `.b-rtable__container` div that occupies all cell and has page-break-inside avoid:

```
.b-rtable__row { 
  height: 1px; // Fix for 100% height;
}
.b-rtable__cell {
  height: inherit;
}
.b-rtable__container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  position: relative; // tried with and without that rule;
  display: table; // tried with and without that rule;
}
```

Added these rules to draw custom `page 1 of 10` text at the bottom of every page, but it's not shown:

```
@page {
  size: auto;
  @bottom-center {
    content: "page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```